# How do I discard the insert of duplicate record in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

I have to insert some data from external source.
My php function runs periodically and fetches results & insert those into table.

There are often results that are already saved.
So they are again inserted.

How do I discard those results that are duplicate so that only new results are entered & duplicate are discarded.

Comment: `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE...` - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Comment: `INSERT IGNORE` will only insert if there is no unique-key violation, else do nothing. `ON DUPLICATE` will update else. `REPLACE` will delete/insert else.

Comment: I try to avoid the `REPLACE` statement as it deletes any unique-key violation, not only those from the primary key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can modify the structure of database tables, the best way would be adding UNIQUE INDEX for column or a number of columns which together uniquely identify a single entry. For example:

ALTER TABLE `table` ADD UNIQUE INDEX `name` (`column_one`, `column_two`);

If the table already contains duplicate records, the altering attempt will result in an error. In that case, you can use IGNORE:

ALTER IGNORE TABLE `table` ADD UNIQUE INDEX `name` (`column_one`, `column_two`);

Keep in mind that creating unnecessarily big indexes will result in:

- more disk space taken up
- slower writing queries (INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE)

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-index.html
(page describes another way of creating indexes but also references ALTER TABLE)

Answer (score 0):

I know this sounds silly, but identify how you can detect duplicates and do not insert them.

This varies depending on your dataset.  If you have a unique field the easiest way would be to set a unique index on that field in the database, a primary key, and the database will not allow a duplicate to be inserted.  Just check your errors and if you get a duplicate key error, disregard as something you are expecting.

Answer (score 0):

That's the point about primary keys, if you define your primary keys wisely you won't have to deal with duplicates because you won't have any.

Answer (score 0):

The `INSERT IGNORE ...` command does exactly this, assuming you have the primary key set on your table.

If you don't have a primary key already, set it to the name or id of your record where having the same name/id would indicate duplicate data.

Comment: A unique key is sufficient, a primary key is just a special case of unique key :)

Answer (score 0):

All relational databases allow both primary keys and unique constraints on a single row.

So if you have a `PERSON` table with a `person_id` column and unique combinations of `first_name` and `last_name` columns, you should make `person_id` the primary key and add a unique constraint on `(first_name, last_name)`.  You won't be able to INSERT a row that violates the unique constraint, even if the primary keys are unique.